# Ninject to inject ILog dependency

Tags: ninject, log4net

I have gone through some other posts in this forum that are related to Ninject and Log4net, but none seemed to address the issue (or resolve it).

Code looks like

```
IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel(new NinjectSettings() { LoadExtensions = true }); 
kernel.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
Program pgm = new Program(kernel.Get<IFSLog>());
```

Exception is thrown in the last line above with message "Error activating ILog.  No matching bindings are available... "

IFSLog is an interface defined in my assembly and its implementation has a dependency on the log4Net Ilog object as below

```
public class Log4NetLog : IFSLog {
  private ILog logger;
  public Log4NetLog(ILog log) {
    this.logger = log;
  }
  ...
}
```

The project references the Ninject.extensions.logging.log4net assembly, so my understanding is that the ILog binding should be identified from there.

Also tried the alternate way of specifying bindings manually

```
public class Bindings : NinjectModule {
    public override void Load() {
        Bind<IFSLog>().To<Log4NetLog>();
    }
}
```

and initializing kernel as

```
IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel(new NinjectSettings() { LoadExtensions = false }, 
  new INinjectModule[] {new Bindings(), new Log4NetModule()});
```

Still same result.  Any help much appreciated, thanks in advance...

Comment: which version of log4net is your `IFSLog` referencing? It *might* be that the ninject extension is referencing a different version.

Comment: log4net version is 1.2.13.0 and ninject.extensions.logging.log4net is 3.2.0.0.

As a work around I added a custom ILogFactory interface that has a GetLogger method which would internall call LogManager.GetLogger and then replaced the IFSLog run time dependency with this new interface.   And inside the various classes, I initialize the ILog member by invoking ILogFactory.GetLogger....  Though it works, still not sure why the earlier attempt did not..  thanks

Comment: well i was just wondering whether this is caused by the ninject.extensions.logging.log4net (3.2.0.0) referencing log4net 1.2.11 and you are referencing a different version (1.2.13.0). Maybe you could downgrade to 1.2.11 and see what happens?
We used to have issues like that with log4net. To be honest, what are you using the ninject log4net logging extensions for? It's only a bunch of simple classes (wrapper for log interface..) + 1 or 2 bindings, i would just roll your own.

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out, what Ninject.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net and Ninject.Extensions.Logging.NLog offer is an abstraction of the Log4net and Nlog interfaces, so you can easily swap NLog with Log4Net.

Both extensions only create a binding for `Ninject.Extensions.Logging.ILoggerFactory` and `Ninject.Extensions.Logging.ILogger`. So that's why there is no binding for `ILog`.

If you inject `ILogger` instead of `ILog` into your `Log4NetLog : IFSLog` it will work.

Or you can skip using the ninject extensions and wire it up yourself and use the log4net `ILog` interface directly (what are you using the `IFSLog` for?).

We used to use log4net `ILog` directly and simplified things like this:

```
internal class LogProvider : Provider<ILog>
{
    protected override ILog CreateInstance(IContext context)
    {
        Type typeLoggerIsInjectedInto = context.Request.ParentContext.Plan.Type;
        return LogManager.GetLogger(typeLoggerIsInjectedInto);
    }
}

IKernel.Bind<ILog>().ToProvider<LogProvider>();
```