# How to get implementing type during Ninject dependency resolve?

Tags: c#, ninject

I use Log4net for logging and I have a lot of objects with an ILog dependency. These dependencies are injected just as the others. I would like to stick to the Log4net logger naming convention so the logger injected to an instance is named after the type of the instance. I have been using the following binding for ILog:

```
Bind<ILog>().ToMethod(ctx =>
    LogManager.GetLogger(ctx.Request.ParentRequest == null ? typeof(object) : ctx.Request.ParentRequest.Service)
);
```

Which is against the naming convention because loggers will be named after the interface not the implementing type.

```
interface IMagic {}

class Magic: IMagic
{
    ILog logger; // The logger injected here should have the name "Magic" instead of IMagic
}
```

I tried a couple of ways to get the implementing type from ctx with no success. Is there any way to get the implementing type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27445150/684096) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24669645/684096) covers your questions but they're not exactly duplicates, so i'll repost this:

```
Bind<ILog>().ToMethod(context =>
             LogManager.GetLogger(context.Request.ParentContext.Plan.Type));
```

so `context.Request.ParentContext.Plan.Type` is the type `ILog` is injected into. If you ever want to do `IResolutionRoot.Get<ILog>()` then there won't be a type to inject `ILog` into and so there won't be a `ParentContext` either. In that case you'll need the `null` check as in your previous solution:

```
Bind<ILog>().ToMethod(context =>
             LogManager.GetLogger(context.Request.ParentContext == null ?
                                  typeof(object) : 
                                  context.Request.ParentContext.Plan.Type));
```

Comment: I have used the ILogger interface of NLog kernel.Bind<ILogger>().ToMethod((context => LogManager.GetLogger(context.Request.ParentContext.Plan.Type.FullName)));