# Get implementing type during ASP.Net core dependency injection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

How do I inject the type of a class into one of its dependencies using the built in ASP.Net dependency injection?

In Startup.Configure I have:

```
services.AddTransient<ILogger>(x => new Logger(???));
```

And my class takes a Logger instance

```
public class ExampleController : ControllerBase
{
    public Example(ILogger logger)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

The Logger constructor should receive typeof(Example) where I have written "???", except this should work for all classes that receive a logger.

The question is very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30457623/how-to-get-implementing-type-during-ninject-dependency-resolve) but I am using an in-house ILogger interface and Logger class, and not using ninject. I effectively wan't to duplicate ninject's "context.Request.ParentContext.Plan.Type" in the other question.

Comment: Which logger are you using, also what is above Example?  Because Example : Controller vs Example work very differently with the built in DI Container for Core.

Comment: I have updated my code and question to clarify. Yes, the class should be a controller. The logger is not Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.

Comment: is it Serilog by chance?

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming you're using `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging`. With that at least, there's no need to register *anything*. The logging is already set up via the call to `CreateDefaultBuilder()` in `Program.cs`. The most you'd need to do is add alternate/additional logging providers, but that's config. You'd never call something like `services.AddTransient` with `ILogger`.

Instead, you handle the type param of the `ILogger` interface via the param you're using to inject it:

```
public class Example
{
    public Example(ILogger<Example> logger)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

You can still store it in a simple `ILogger` ivar, without a generic type, but the param you're injecting into needs to specify the type param.

Alternatively, if you're looking for something a little more flexible, you can inject `ILoggerFactory` instead, and then use `GetType()` to provide the type:

```
public class Example
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public Example(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        _logger = _loggerFactory.CreateLogger(GetType())
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, actually we're using an in-house ILogger and Logger that wraps a third-party logger.

Answer (score 1):

One of available solutions is:

Initialize your logger (NLog, Log4Net, you-name-it) like this:

```
WebHost.ConfigureLogging((context, builder) => ...init your logger engine here...)
```

Then, use generic version of ILogger<> instead of just ILogger type:

```
public class Example
{
    public Example(ILogger<Example> logger)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.